# Replacing lambda expressions in LINQ queries through NET/Link

Tags: .netlink

We have an IEnumerable Objects in C# that we want to import into the Wolfram Financial Platform. In the current C# API, we use LINQ queries to select from the Objects the specific Object that we need. In Wolfram Financial Platform we can import the IEnumerable Objects through NET/Link (More info: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/Overview.html)

Once the object is imported, there does not seem to be a way to use LINQ queries even after importing the LINQ library. Additionally, lambda expressions used in the LINQ queries do not have a clear replacement in Wolfram Financial Platform.

**Examples**

C#

```
Object.Where(x => x.Property == Target).FirstOrDefault();
```

Wolfram

```
???[# == #.Property &, Object]`FirstOrDefault[];
```

**Current Attempt + Error**

C#

```
Option call = optionChain.Options
                                  .Where(x => (x.Expiration - DateTime.Today).TotalDays > 7 && (x.Expiration - DateTime.Today).TotalDays < 45 && x.PutCall == PutCall.Call && x.Class.Settlement == null)
                                  .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(msft.Trade.Last - x.Strike)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Wolfram (baby steps version)

```
call = optionChain@Options`FirstOrDefault[];
```

Error

"No public instance method named "FirstOrDefault" exists for 
the .NET type "Core.Data.MarketData.OptionChain".

Also tried using First[optionChain@Options]; and got the non-atomic error. Found that could mean an infinite loop or non-existent variable. Checked that optionChain@Options exists by outputting it through NETConsole, which makes me think that NETObjects won't work with First[] (?)

**End Goal**

Import specific values from a C# API with LINQ queries, or equivalent, intact into Wolfram Financial Platform for the purpose of writing a program in the Wolfram Financial Platform language (not allowed to do it the other way around, as much as I want to).

*[Originally posted this on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142257/using-linq-in-wolfram), but it looks like it is pending removal due to being "off-topic"*

Comment: Does `optionChain@Options` give a Wolfram list of option objects?  If so have you tried `Select`? Something like ``Select[DateDifference[#`Expiration - Today, "Day"] > Quantity[7, "Days"] &]@(optionChain@Options)``.  [**`Elements of Lists`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ElementsOfLists.html) guide

Comment: optionChain@Options returns a System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Data.Securities.Option] object, which gives a non-atomic exception when using Select.

Comment: Add `@ToArray[]` immediately after `Options` inside of the bracket.  This will convert it into a Wolfram list.  Then the `Select` should be happy.  Well the only part I am unsure about is the ``#`Expiration`` bit.

Comment: Sorry, the `-` in `DateDifference` should be a `,`.

Comment: Alright, cooking with gas, now. The DateDifference is having difficulties with the Expiration's .NETDateTime object, but now Select, First, etc. work with the Options object.

Comment: Currently

`call = First[# &]@
  Select[DateDifference[DateObject[#@Expiration@Day] - Today, "Day"] <
        Quantity[15, "Days"] && #@Strike == 45 &]@(optionChain@
     Options@ToArray[])`

Error

`DateDifference::date: Expression -42449.days cannot be interpreted as a date specification. >>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37357/discussion-between-user1981756-and-edmund).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to this is to convert the .Net collection into a Wolfram `List` and then use `Select`.  `ToArray` can be called on `Options` for this conversion.

Also (from our chat), since `Expiration` is not static in C# then `@` can be used instead of `` ` ``.  Combining these we get:

```
Select[DateDifference[DateObject[#@Expiration /@ {Year, Month, Day}], 
     Today, "Day"] < Quantity[15, "Days"] &]@
 (optionChain @ Options @ ToArray[])
```

The components of `Expiration` are taken into a Wolfram `DateObject` specification by `#@Expiration /@ {Year, Month, Day}`

Additional conditions can be added to `Select`.

Hope this helps.